# google cse load after page complete loaded

Tags: jquery

I have a question, how to make google cse to load after page have completely loaded.

i have seen this on http://www.9lessons.info/ on top right.

Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the script of google cse as last as possible